# Reference Library questions

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been developing my access applications im Access 2003 (on a windows XP platform) for a number of years, the apps seem to do just fine on later versions of access.

I finally purchased a new laptop with windows 10, and office 2016.
I don't use any bound forms, and execute the sql statements via vba coding (ADOB.Connection, ADOB.Recordset)I've always included the "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library", and " Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library" references.

Now that I've upgraded my software, should I be using different references? I plan on building apps that deploying some of the apps to possibly run on "Runtime Versions" of Access.
I'm not knowledgeable enough at this point to really know differences or advantages/disadvantages of the different versions

Comment: You can use late bindings to be compatible with any version and any installed version of ADO. Read here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation for more info on early vs late bindings.

Comment: Thanks, If I use late bindings, do I need to uncheck the references in the vb editor?

Comment: Nope. It's just not a problem if you don't add them.

Comment: Thanks again, I canged